# Alternatives to domain transfer

Tags: web-hosting, domain-transfer

Last month I changed hosting providers to HostGator and transferred my domain name to them. Since then I've had nothing but headaches dealing with their support, so I set up my own web server at home to host from (it's only a small portfolio site). My home network connection is a dynamic IP address, so I'd like to use No-IP as my registry because of their services specifically for dynamic IPs. I made the mistake of signing up for a 3 year discount deal with HostGator, so I really need to get my money back. But their money-back guarantee only lasts for 45 days, and I'm still subject to the 60 day wait period to transfer my domain name. What can I do in this situation? I need the refund, even if it means leaving my domain open to public purchase for awhile, but I'm hoping there is a way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not technical but about contracts.

**Domain transfer IS the correct alternative.** If your domain has any value (economic, reputation, even vanity), you should NEVER let it expire and become available. If the domain has any fame, it will most likely be automatically bought by someone who will claim "ransoms" if you want it back. Compared to that, already paid hosting fees are small and could be regarded as doctrine money.

Usually it is wise to separate hosting from domain registration and hold your domain on a registrar that guarantees the sovereign ownership and full control of your domain name. Luckily, HostGator doesn't seem malicious, since they are providing directions on [how to get the authorization key](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/domain-names-buy-sell-manage/what-is-my-epp-code-or-authorization-key).

Secondly you might benefit having DNS somewhere you can add your own records if you are ever willing to have any services on different providers.

Comment: My domain really doesn't carry much reputation/ranking, nor do I really need it to. But I'm interested on your point about separating registry from hosting. Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: Many registrars are just providing service on registering domain and most of the hosting companies are not registrars themselves but buying the domain from a registrar for you. Some malicious hosting companies are buying the domain names for themselves as they were only renting it to you. That's an unethical way of holding the customers.